# Can't browse local domains without a network connection

Tags: firefox, networking, localhost

I have a few different PHP sites running on local domains (i.e. domains set to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts) so I can work on them without any network delay.

I'd like to be able to work on these sites when I have no connection at all (e.g. on the bus or in the park) but my browser (Firefox on LinuxMint) can't load the local pages when there's no network connection (it doesn't have to have Internet access, but it must have a working network connection). Note that it can load a site via local IP addresses or "localhost", but not using any other local domain name.

I'd like to create some kind of local network that makes the Network Manager show a valid connection even when there is no LAN adapter present. Or alternatively a way to make Firefox work with the local domains without needing the network would be just as good.

Reproduce this problem as follows:
- Run a local web-server such as micro_httpd and serve a test site
- Set up some other names for 127.0.0.1 in addition to localhost in your /etc/hosts file such as foo.bar
- Test that your site works from localhost and from foo.bar
- Unplug your network cable
- Test again, only localhost works, not foo.bar
- Test with wget, both work fine

Comment: Please can you specify the server you are using? Anyway I think you accesing them through WAN instead of LAN probably in the setup of the server should be specified

Comment: This has nothing to do with what type of server software I'm running (however for the record its Nginx) and it has nothing to do with WAN. The problem is very simple, Firefox will not load a page if there is no network connection even if the page is local as determined by /etc/hosts. This is a problem with Firefox, e.g. wget can load the page no problem.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue.  Either of these work for me, in Firefox go to `about:config` and click `I'll be careful, I promise!`, search for `network.dns` then either:

- Set `network.dns.disableIPv6` to `false`

or

- Add your local domain names to `network.dns.localDomains`

I think the latter is probably the better of the two options, but either works for me.

Comment: Just adding my local alias to `network.dns.localDomains` solved the issue for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a little to [Lee Kowalkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30945/lee-kowalkowski) answer:

I have modified below at `admin:config` in my firefox developer edition 61.0b3 (64-bit)

`network.dns.localDomains` added `localhost` as I bind my local sites with localhost

Answer (score 0):

I haven't needed this functionality for a couple years and noticed now as of Firefox 60 that there is no problem any more.

[This old Bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=967792) mentions the issue and says it was resolved by adding the *about:config* key **network.dns.offline-localhost**, perhaps that's set to *true* by default now which is why it works?